# Why does two Activity using the same theme have different status bar color?

Tags: android

Main Activity and Chat Activity use the same theme:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".View.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
```

---

```
    <activity
        android:name=".View.ChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chat"
        android:parentActivityName=".View.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="ocm.my.chat.View.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/statusTranGray </item>
</style>
```

However the status bars' color are different:

[image]
[image]

I cannot figure out why this odd thing happen, please help.

color.xml

[image]

---

activity_chat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ocm.my.chat.View.ChatActivity">



    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/chat_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:title="fsdasdfsda"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"/>


    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_chat"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chat_toolbar"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

content_chat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msg_type"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:hint="Input message"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.75"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_chat_send"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_chat_send"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textColor="@color/background_material_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/msg_type"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_msg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/msg_type"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ocm.my.chat.View.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
          />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ocm.my.chat.View.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Addition

Change android:statusBarColor property to red color. Both the two activity status bars' color look the same. Both red.

Comment: Change `android:statusBarColor` property to red color. See what will happen.

Comment: The `Toolbar` of two activities are't the same, you can set only one `Toolbar` xml using `include` tag.

Comment: @mklimek After changing the color to red, they look the same red.

Comment: @mklimek Does it have something about my half-transparent status bar color settings?

Comment: @L.Swifter Two `Toolbar` will have different elements in the future, so I don't want to use the same`Toolbar`.

Comment: @guo it might be something with transparency. Make sure there's nothing more behind the first or second activity. Play with red and its transparency as well.